# automated property with get or set only in visual studio 2015

Tags: c#

I saw many answers here regarding auto properties with get or set only. Everyone says that it is not possible, and tries to explain.
But in `VS2015`, it is possible:

```
public string Foo { get; }
```

is OK.
But:

```
public string Foo { set; }
```

gives an error.

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: new c# 6 features. you can assign `Foo` in the constructor.

Comment: Has autoimplemented set-only property any sense to you?

Comment: Yes. for example: set a date of birth, but do not have access to the date, just to the age which will be a get only.

Comment: But how will you return the age based on the date of birth that you set if you do not have access to the date of birth?

Comment: From the same class you have!

Comment: No you have not because your property has no getter.

Comment: An automatic property **must** have a getter. It may be private, but it **must** exist, otherwise it is just like an empty method with a parameter, what's the point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because there is no sense of set-only auto-implemented property.

Your code could contains set-only property because it can cause a class state. But you can't do it with auto-implemented setter.

Instead of it you can initialize your read-only property with [initializers for auto-properties](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6#initializers-for-auto-properties) or [getter-only auto-properties](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6#getter-only-auto-properties) and then get the value:

```
public int Foo { get; } = 3;
```

You can add whole expression to your initializer:

```
public string Config { get; } = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(string connectionString =
(string)Properties.Settings.Default.Context?["connectionString"])
   ? connectionString 
   : "<none>";
```

Also you can use [Ctor assignment to getter-only autoprops](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Languages-features-in-C%23-6-and-VB-14).

Comment: "It's because there is no sense of set-only auto-implemented property". Why not? see my remark above

Comment: If you will set date of birth you can't have access to it for calculating age. It can implemented only with next code: `public DateTime BirthDate { private get; set; }`

Comment: Exacly what I asked him above, I presume he meant that the age will be set in the set of the BirthDate but then it is not an auto-property

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want something like this

```
public class A
{
    public int Foo { set { Foo = value; } // Set only properties can't 
                                          // be auto implemented

    public int CalculateWithFoo()
    {
        int Bar;

        Bar = Foo - 5; // Compile error: "A get or set accessor expected"

        return Bar;
    }
}
```

But if you do this you will get a **A get or set accessor expected** error. So you cannot access a set only property even inside your class.

As other have said, you can make it

```
public int Foo { private get; set; }
```

So it will only be accessible inside your class

Answer (score 0):

**If you are going to create a Property then it must be accessible at least in the same class.**

If you would like that your property should be accessible only inside the class in which it has been declared then you can use

```
string FullName { private get; set; }
```

But if you want that your property should be assigned from anywhere but can be read only inside the class in which it has been declared then use

```
class User { public string FullName { private get; set; } }
```

……………

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {     User u = new User();
            u.FullName = "Banketeshvar Narayan";
            Console.WriteLine(u.FullName);            
        }
```

And it will give the compile time error:

*The property or indexer 'User.FullName' cannot be used in this context because the get accessor is inaccessible.*

So in the above case you can assign the value of the property from anywhere but it can be read inside the same class only.

In C# 6.0 some new ways has been introduced for declaring and assigning a property

**Way1: Readonly automatically implemented properties**

```
public string FirstName { get; }
```

If you do not assign its value then it will return the default value.

**Way 2:  Assigning value at the time of declaration:**

```
public string FirstName { get; } = "Banketeshvar";
```

**Way 3: Assigning value In a constructor in the same class:**

```
User() { FirstName  = "Banketeshvar"; }
```

**Way 4: Purely ReadOnly Property (Expression-bodied properties)**

If you are looking for purely Readonly property then go for this

```
public string FullName => "Manish Sharma";
```

now you cannot assign value of “FullName” propery from constructor. If you try to do that it will throw the following exceptions

***“Property or indexer 'Person.FullName' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only”***